# jquery animate but then come back to normal

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Consider a div "dMyDiv"

I notice in jquery I can animate so this:

```
$( "#dMyDiv").animate({
         backgroundColor: "#aa0000"
  }, 1000 );
```

Brings a red like colored background to my div.  But is there a way to then after say 10 seconds
go back to my normal white background of my div?  I see there is a callback function but Im not sure if it is possible to start the animation, and once the animation is done to go back to my regular background (before the animation).  Should I just do this:

```
 $( "#dMyDiv").animate({
             backgroundColor: "#aa0000"
          }, 1000, function() {
           $(#dMyDiv").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fff" }, 1000);
          };
);
```

Meaning after the red animate, just animate again to white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it with this guys:

http://jsfiddle.net/aN7qz/

Here is the code:

```
$( "#myDiv").animate({ 
             backgroundColor: "#aa0000" 
          },
             1000, 
             function() { 
                 $("#myDiv").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fff" }, 1000);
             }
                     );
```

Comment: I thought you wanted to wait 10 seconds and then reanimate?  If so, check my answer for how to do that. If not and you want to immediately call it after the first animation, you've got it!

Comment: @Scott - Well really I was just looking to go from one animation to another, and if you think about it I can set the seconds to animate so this should do.  I will still +1 you for your hard dedicated work :).

Comment: oJM86o: My answer was correct and remained as the accepted one for a few time. Now you have responded yourself with less functionality and removed the accepted answer to put your own answer as the accepted one. In consequence, my reputation downgraded for 15 points. ¬¬

Answer (score 7):

You're right. the third parameter is a function that executes once the animation is complete.

```
$("#dMyDiv").stop().animate({backgroundColor:'#aa0000'},1000,function(){
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor:'#fff'},1000);
});
```

Comment: If you don't stop the animation, and is running at the time it's triggered again, it will get into a kind of queue, making it look weird. For example, you trigger the animation by clicking a button, you do it repeatedly 10 times. If you don't stop it'll run lots of times until finishes.

Answer (score 3):

You could use setTimeout:

```
$("#dMyDiv").stop(true, true).animate({

    backgroundColor: "#aa0000"

}, 1000, function() {

   setTimeout(function() {       

       $(#dMyDiv").animate({ 

           backgroundColor: "#fff" 

       }, 1000);

   }, 10 * 1000);

});
```

Comment: If you don't stop the animation, and is running at the time it's triggered again, it will get into a kind of queue, making it look weird. For example, you trigger the animation by clicking a button, you do it repeatedly 10 times. If you don't stop it'll run lots of times until finishes.

Comment: lu1s is correct and you want to use [`.stop(true, true)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) for a smoother transition. Check out the link documentation as to why.

Comment: Thanks Scott, didn't know about those parameters. It clears the queue.